# Just lost a bunch of ubuntu-desktop dependencies attempting to uninstall mysql

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql

I ran `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*` and didn't notice that it also had `ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal gnome-control-center ...` and a whole bunch more.

I've not rebooted yet, but I'm worried my system will go belly up once I do.

1. What will happen on reboot?
2. Why on earth would it remove those packages when it doesn't start with `mysql`

Comment: Simply reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` before rebooting. Apt has several safeguards to prevent mass-removals. Perhaps you have disabled or ignored them.

Comment: yeah that did seem to install the same packages that was removed. I still wondering however how apt decided to remove those when  I asked for `mysql*`

Comment: Because those packages depend on one one or more of the `mysql*` packages. Be careful with using wildcards when removing anything from your system. `apt-get` should have told you which packages are going to removed, reading before hitting enter would have saved you the headache.